# QUERY PARA SEPARAR SUMAS EN DIFERENTES COLUMNAS DE DIFERENTES TABLAS

Tags: mysql, sql

Me gustaria saber como separar las sumas que tengo de un query en diferentes columnas, es decir que me tome la suma en otra columna y no una sola.

este es el codigo:

```
SELECT SUM(contratos.Valor_contrato) as totalcontratos
FROM contratos 
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(ventas.VALOR_TOTAL) AS totalventas
FROM ventas
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(prorrogas.Valor_mes) as totalpagosprorrogas
FROM prorrogas
```

[image: Este es el resultado del query]

**NOTA: Es importante tener en cuenta que los campos están en diferentes tablas**, Agradeceria mucho su colaboracion.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si vos queres todo en una fila.. entonces vas a tener que ejecutar un solo select donde cada columna sea el valor que queres.. y para eso nada mejor que usar subconsultas...

```
select
    (SELECT SUM(contratos.Valor_contrato) FROM contratos) as totalcontratos,
    (SELECT SUM(ventas.VALOR_TOTAL) FROM ventas) AS totalventas,
    (SELECT SUM(prorrogas.Valor_mes) FROM prorrogas) as totalpagosprorrogas
from dual
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, te lo agradezco montones.